# create web with xlsx data. html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xlsx

i´ve been looking online and i can´t find a way to use my xlsx file to create the content on my web.
I am already aware of the ways i can read an xlsx file uploaded by the user, but i need to use the xlsx in the server. I´ve reached the conclusion that that won´t be as easy as it seems. but please someone would tell me the easyest way, or anyway.
At this moment i am using

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
```

and in the upload function i have a function that works the excell and print the results I need, all another history. I just read the excell using getelementbyid("fileupload"), works fine. but i need to be able to use an xlsx that I the programer have saved on the server. So i can´t use this method to get the info, obbiously the user cannot select the excell cause the objective of the web it is the user can ask the data from the one i own, the one I can modify, the one in the server, the same everytime.
please, can somebody help. Ive looked online 1000 diferent ways to read the data from input, it is weird to me that i can´t find info on using one excell to populate the data of the web, i thought it would be the most common.

I am not sure i explained myself well enought so i will try in a diferent manner:
I am making a web that will be used to consult the state of some diseases in farm animals. that information is contained on an excell that i have and need to show results in my web. i need a simple (if posible) way to acces my xlsx with my code to filter it in the needed way.

Comment: As i understand, you need an XLSX parser for php?

Comment: i can´t use php... i need something that does the same as the input file, but loads the file straight from the server at the time the web is open.

Comment: So, if you want just to preview an XLSX file in your html page, you can use Embedded IFrame ( e.g: Google sheets or Microsoft one drive)

Comment: not to preview, when you upload one with input file, you do not see it, you can access it with code, but you do not see it.

Comment: Look at this project can it help you?, https://openbase.io/js/js-xlsx/documentation     demo: https://oss.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/

Comment: it is extense, the demo works exactly as the code that i already have, it also ask for the user to upload the file. I need to use the file i already have on the server, not input required... .